# Multiple output documents: can I refer from a result-document to my original?

Tags: xslt

I have an XSLT that is used to generate a series of output documents based on input documents. 
Basically, I have 2 directories, `in` and `out` and I use the XSLT to create files in directory `out` based on files with the same name in directory `in`.

My base XML (filelist.xml) contains the list of documents:

```
<file name="1 old.xml"><...></file>
<file name="2 new.xml"><...></file>
```

The files in directory `in` contain `<source>` and `<target>` nodes.

and my XSLT:

```
<xsl:template match="file">
    <xsl:result-document method="xml" href="{outputfolder\@name}">
    <xsl:when test="unparsed-text-available(inputfolder\@name)">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="document(inputfolder\@name)"/>
    </xsl:when>
</xsl:template>
```

Now I want to process the files in `in` based on their filename:

- if the filename contains "new" I want to just copy all the nodes in '2 new.xml',
- if the filename contains "old" I want to modify one of the nodes in '1 old.xml'.

This is how I modify the node:

```
<xsl:template match="target">
    <xsl:choose>
         <xsl:when test="...">
             <xsl:copy>
                 <xsl:copy-of select="ancestor::*/source"/>
             </xsl:copy>    
         </xsl:when>
         <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
         </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:template>
```

Inside this template, the current node is the `<target>` inside `1 old.xml`. At this location, how do I run a node test that looks at the node in `filelist.xml` that created my output document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is to bind a global variable to the principal input document:

```
<xsl:variable name="filelist" select="/" as="document-node(element(file))"/>
```

and you can then refer to it from anywhere in the stylesheet as `$filelist`.

The `as` attribute helps to make things clear for the human reader and gives you an automatic check that the stylesheet is being applied to the right kind of source document.

Incidentally, you're playing with fire by using strings that contain spaces as URIs (and you also seem to be typing backslashes where forwards slashes are required).

Comment: I see, that gets me the root node of the filelist. Is there a way to see which `<file>` node was used to create the document that contains <target>? (I've made some changes to the question which I hope clarify things)

Comment: I'm converting the strings to proper URIs, thanks to some hints here on SO. Just skipped those details for the example.